# the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b

Tags: visual-studio-2008, winapi, windows-7, 64-bit

I have a win32 application. Trying to run in windows 7 64-bit OS in VisualStudio 2008. Have installed x64 Environment. So when i'm trying to run my project i'm getting this error "the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b". I have no link errors too. Anyone any suggestions please.

Comment: I had something like that when the loader failed to load app's DLLs. I don't remember the error code, though.

Comment: @Alex so what were your troubleshoot steps?

Comment: Well, I used the kernel debugger to see that. In my case it turned out that the system was badly corrupted and couldn't start any app. Rebooted, everything worked. In any case, I'd recommend to step through the app in the debugger (WinDbg), from the very beginning (from before main, I mean).

Comment: @Alex Thank you for reminding me about debugger from which i found dll is not loaded. And rebuilt that dll and used it. Now its working perfectly.. Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i got the same issue as you. I had a application Win32. When i converted this application Win32 to X64 with Visual Studio 2010, the application x64 is compiled successfully. But when i ran it, it generated the error message: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00000b7). Click ok to close the application".

It took few days to fix it by changing many setting of Configuration properties->linker.
Especially, i changed the setting of Linker.Manifestfile.Generate Manifest = No (/MANIFEST:NO)
It worked to my application.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It can be processorArchitecture mismatch in manifest in assemblyIdentity or in dependencyAssembly.