# The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) with opencv3.2 and VS2010

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying to run an openCV code in VS2010. The Build is proper, but the Debug Run causes issue. An error saying *The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b)* occurs

I have seen earlier posts on the same issue and I have tried the same but the issue is not getting solved.
[the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646159/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc00007b)

[VC++ 64bit EXE application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365059/vc-64bit-exe-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0x000007b-error)

I am sure that this is not a duplicate post. The issue is somewhere related to 32 bit and 64 bit dll files.

**Configuration:** 64 bit Windows OS, VS2010, OpenCV3.2, Win32 application project, Solutions configuration- Debug, Solution Platforms-x64.

I have tried various other ways:

1. Re-Installing redistributables, 2010, 2012, 2013 and 2015
2. Selecting Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols->Microsoft Symbol servers
3. Installed new DirectX SDK

   The procedure I followed for installation is :

   - Downloaded OpenCV3.2. Extracted the folder in C:\opencv3.2
   - Environment Variables: OPENCV_DIR: C:\opencv3.2\opencv\build, OPENCV_DIR: C:\opencv3.2\opencv\build\x64\vc14, Path: C:\opencv3.2\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin;C:\opencv3.2\opencv\build\bin
   - Created a new Win32 console application.
   - Right click project -> properties
   - C/C++ -> General->Additional Include Direcories -> C:\opencv3.2\opencv\build\include, C:\opencv3.2\opencv\build\include\opencv, C:\opencv3.2\opencv\build\include\opencv2
   - Linker->General-> Additional Library Directories->C:\opencv3.2\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib
   - Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies->opencv_world320.lib
     opencv_world320d.lib
   - Linker->Manifest File->Generate Manifest: NO

The error messages obtained below, just copied the single error message.
        ***'new_project.exe': Loaded    'C:\opencv3.2\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_world320.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

        The program '[5096] new_project.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).***

Please help me to solve this.

I also tried running the .exe file generated by VS2010 in Dependency Walker, I get the below issue. I am not able to interpret it.
[image]

Regards,
Prajwal Sapare

Comment: you try load 64bit dll to 32bit process. as result and got `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`

Comment: @RbMm : What should I do now? should i build my own libraries for 32bit dll?

Comment: i think opencv have libs/dll for both 32 and 64 bit. but need correct use it. for 32-bit include `C:\opencv3.2\opencv\build\vc14\lib` or where 32 bit located ? but not `C:\opencv3.2\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib`

Comment: I do not find 32bit dlls... What should I do next?

Comment: @Prajwal_7, build them from source