# Compiling SDL2 windows EXE from Linux with mingw 'The application was unable to start correctly'

Tags: c, linux, windows, cross-compiling, sdl-2

So I'm trying to build this example SDL 2 program on VSCode on Ubuntu 21.10:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_timer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 
    // retutns zero on success else non-zero
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        printf("error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("GAME", // creates a window
                                       SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                       SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                       1000, 1000, 0);
 
    // triggers the program that controls
    // your graphics hardware and sets flags
    Uint32 render_flags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED;
 
    // creates a renderer to render our images
    SDL_Renderer* rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, render_flags);
 
    // creates a surface to load an image into the main memory
    SDL_Surface* surface;
 
    // loads image to our graphics hardware memory.
    SDL_Texture* tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(rend, surface);
 
    // clears main-memory
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
 
    // let us control our image position
    // so that we can move it with our keyboard.
    SDL_Rect dest;
 
    // connects our texture with dest to control position
    SDL_QueryTexture(tex, NULL, NULL, &dest.w, &dest.h);
 
    // adjust height and width of our image box.
    dest.w /= 6;
    dest.h /= 6;
 
    // sets initial x-position of object
    dest.x = (1000 - dest.w) / 2;
 
    // sets initial y-position of object
    dest.y = (1000 - dest.h) / 2;
 
    // controls annimation loop
    int close = 0;
 
    // speed of box
    int speed = 300;
 
    // annimation loop
    while (!close) {
        SDL_Event event;
 
        // Events management
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
 
            case SDL_QUIT:
                // handling of close button
                close = 1;
                break;
 
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                // keyboard API for key pressed
                switch (event.key.keysym.scancode) {
                case SDL_SCANCODE_W:
                case SDL_SCANCODE_UP:
                    dest.y -= speed / 30;
                    break;
                case SDL_SCANCODE_A:
                case SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT:
                    dest.x -= speed / 30;
                    break;
                case SDL_SCANCODE_S:
                case SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN:
                    dest.y += speed / 30;
                    break;
                case SDL_SCANCODE_D:
                case SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT:
                    dest.x += speed / 30;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
 
        // right boundary
        if (dest.x + dest.w > 1000)
            dest.x = 1000 - dest.w;
 
        // left boundary
        if (dest.x < 0)
            dest.x = 0;
 
        // bottom boundary
        if (dest.y + dest.h > 1000)
            dest.y = 1000 - dest.h;
 
        // upper boundary
        if (dest.y < 0)
            dest.y = 0;
 
        // clears the screen
        SDL_RenderClear(rend);
        SDL_RenderCopy(rend, tex, NULL, &dest);
 
        // triggers the double buffers
        // for multiple rendering
        SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
 
        // calculates to 60 fps
        SDL_Delay(1000 / 60);
    }
 
    // destroy texture
    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
 
    // destroy renderer
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
 
    // destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
     
    // close SDL
    SDL_Quit();
 
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile for Linux, it works just fine. It basically does nothing but creates a window on the screen named "GAME".
But I am also trying to cross-compile for Windows using minGW.
These are the commands I am using to do that:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -L/home/russell/Windows_Dev/SDL2-devel-2.0.16-mingw/SDL2-2.0.16/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -I/home/russell/Windows_Dev/SDL2-devel-2.0.16-mingw/SDL2-2.0.16/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -fstack-protector -std=c17 -Wall -g -o obj/main.o -c src/main.c
```

and

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -L/home/russell/Windows_Dev/SDL2-devel-2.0.16-mingw/SDL2-2.0.16/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -I/home/russell/Windows_Dev/SDL2-devel-2.0.16-mingw/SDL2-2.0.16/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -fstack-protector -std=c17 -Wall -g -o build/Test.exe obj/main.o -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows -lm
```

which compiles perfectly fine. However, if I try to run the program on my Windows 10 machine, I get an error that says:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)."
```

Comment: Can you rebuild with `-v` and show the output?

Comment: I would also try removing `-fstack-protector`.

Comment: Could this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7646159/1212012

Comment: `-fstack-protector` appeared to be the problem. Can't remember why I had that in there. Thanks @HolyBlackCat!

Comment: FWIW, I tried running MSYS2 GCC using Wine, and `-fstack-protector` works. It also works when cross-compiling with Clang, using libs from MSYS2 GCC.